# Bash tail -f with while-read and pipe hangs

Tags: bash, pipe, tail

In Bash, piping `tail -f` to a `read` loop blocks indefinitely.

```
while read LINE0 
do 
    echo "${LINE0}"; 
done < <( tail -n 3 -f /tmp/file0.txt | grep '.*' ) 
# hangs
```

Remove the `-f` or `| grep '.*'`, then the loop will iterate.

The following does *not* hang.

```
tail -n 3 -f /tmp/file0.txt | grep '.*'
```

What causes this behavior?

Is there anyway in Bash to follow a file and read in a pipe expression?

Comment: If you use `-f`, it is supposed to "hang" in the sense that `tail` keeps waiting for more lines to be added to the file.  When I try `tail -n 3 -f /tmp/file0.txt | wc`, it hangs for me.  It should hang because `wc` never gets an end-of-file signal.  Are you sure that it doesn't hang for you?

Comment: That's a good point.  I corrected my question, replacing `wc` with `grep`.

Comment: `grep` may not "hang" but it does have buffering issues.  It may not print anything until there is enough to fill a buffer.

Comment: Thanks @John1024!  I demonstrated that you are correct by:  I added lines to the file, and the loop finally iterated.  It looks like the buffering is not in the `tail -f`, but in the `read`.  If I grep for an expression that is only in a couple of lines, even if the file is grown large, the loop will not iterate.  I now need to figure out how to stop `read` from buffering.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the pipeline, `grep`'s output is buffered. With the GNU implementation of `grep`, you can force flush the output after each line with `--line-buffered` ([documentation here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-_002d_002dline_002dbuffered)); for example:

```
tail -n 3 -f /tmp/file0.txt | grep --line-buffered '.*' |
  while IFS= read -r LINE0 
  do 
    printf '%s\n' "${LINE0}"
  done
```

Answer (score 1):

Greg's Wiki has a comprehensive article about buffering: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009

The technique that worked for me (Popos 20.04, Ubuntu 20.04) was using `stdbuf` to do line buffering.  Their example:

```
tail -f logfile | stdbuf -oL grep 'foo bar' | awk ...
```

My use case:

```
journalctl --output=json -t poke-stats -f |\
 stdbuf -oL jq -r '.__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP' |\
 stdbuf -oL awk '{print $1-last;last=$1}'
```